# ASP MVC how to pass an argument from a view to a method in Controller C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Am new to mvc and I'm currently making a simple mvc 4 project. I kindly like to know how I can pass an argument from a view, to a method inside my Controller. Here is my code sample from the View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("GetStudentsScore", "StudentsScore")">@item.idcourse</a>
}
```

Here is the method am calling from the control layer:

```
public ActionResult GetStudentsScore(string courseId)
{
    List<StudentScore> resultToReturn = new List<StudentScore>();
    List<StudentScore> resultFromTable = dataContext.StudentScores.ToList();
    foreach (StudentScore item in resultFromTable)
    {
        if (item.courseid == courseId)
        {
            resultToReturn.Add(item);
        }  
    }
    return View(resultToReturn.ToList()); 
}
```

I want to be able to click the link and then call "GetStudentsScore" method in my control layer but I dont know how to pass the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your link to

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.idcourse, "GetStudentsScore", "StudentsScore", new { courseId = item.idcourse})
}
```

Note this assumes that property `idcourse` is typeof `string`

Side note: You can simplify your controller code to

```
public ActionResult GetStudentsScore(string courseId)
{
    var model = dataContext.StudentScores.Where(x => x.courseid == courseId).ToList();
    return View(model); 
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, yes, idcourse is of type string. am very grateful.